# cron the same python script (with venv) multiple times and different arguments only runs one

Tags: python, cron

I have the following crontab installed, where it is running the same command with 4 different arguments, file1-file4:

```
1 12 * * * cd /home/me/scripts && /home/me/scripts/venv/bin/python /home/me/scripts/myscript.py file1.py 0 100
2 12 * * * cd /home/me/scripts && /home/me/scripts/venv/bin/python /home/me/scripts/myscript.py file2.py 101 200
3 12 * * * cd /home/me/scripts && /home/me/scripts/venv/bin/python /home/me/scripts/myscript.py file3.py 201 300
4 12 * * * cd /home/me/scripts && /home/me/scripts/venv/bin/python /home/me/scripts/myscript.py file4.py 301 400
```

I'm trying to get the 4 to start a minute apart just after noon.

These are of the form:

```
m h * * * cd workingdir && get_the_right_virtualenv.py myscript.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

However, when I look at output, it's actually only running the first one, not all 4---2-4 are entirely ignored.

This is the log I'm getting, which seems to show that the scripts kicked off correctly:

```
$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Jun 16 11:39:01 me CRON[25247]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Jun 16 12:01:01 me CRON[25387]: (me) CMD (cd /home/me/scripts && /home/me/scripts/venv/bin/python /home/me/scripts/myscript.py file1.py 0 100)
Jun 16 12:01:40 me CRON[25385]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 16 12:02:01 me CRON[25399]: (me) CMD (cd /home/me/scripts && /home/me/scripts/venv/bin/python /home/me/scripts/myscript.py file2.py 101 200)
Jun 16 12:03:01 me CRON[25413]: (me) CMD (cd /home/me/scripts && /home/me/scripts/venv/bin/python /home/me/scripts/myscript.py file3.py 201 300)
Jun 16 12:04:01 me CRON[25425]: (me) CMD (cd /home/me/scripts && /home/me/scripts/venv/bin/python /home/me/scripts/myscript.py file4.py 301 400)
Jun 16 12:09:01 me CRON[25446]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Jun 16 12:17:01 me CRON[25514]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 16 12:39:01 me CRON[25785]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
Jun 16 13:06:01 me CRON[25423]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 16 13:09:01 me CRON[25959]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
```

When I look at my output, I see that only the first one is actually producing output---the others are not.  Is it not possible to run the same script with multiple arguments in cron?  I see they're getting independent PIDs, so I didn't suspect the script was locking, but it looks like it may be?

How can I get cron to actually run all 4 scripts?

Comment: The crons look fine to me. Is there any reason why you are passing arguments of the kind `file1.py`?

Comment: How do you know that not all 4 are running?  What is the effect you're expecting to see, and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: The file1-file4 files contain some config arguments that are loaded by the main script.  Once the script runs, it dumps output to a database, but each day when I look at the database, it only gets the output of the records inserted by the first run, not all 4 (ie, it is 4x too small and the batch ID I write in tells me only the first ran).